# DOM loading progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

I'm using a simple overlay with a loading bar image before my whole page is loaded.

This is my code :

```
<div id="loadingOverlay">
     <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading bar" />
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#loadingOverlay').fadeOut();
});
```

It works but I'd like a real loading bar that fills as the page loads.

I guess  I'll have to find the weight of the page and then calculte of many bytes have been "*downloaded*" but I don't know how to check that, especially with jQuery.

Maybe I complicate the problem, but is there a way to do that?

Also, I found this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/huyusu/3/edit) that seems to work but its focused on images, I just want to do that on the whole page and its content.

Comment: Tried [Pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is it possible to configure Pace loader with my logo and the progress count just below?

Comment: Take a look at the Themes that are in the page @Rory McCrossan gave you. You can take one of those and edit it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo . It seems that this is the simpliest way to do that.